# amazon sqs sendmessage method failure c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to execute this function, but the program is breaking without catching any exception, can't figure it out whats going on. Can any one help please. 
I am using this function (method) in windows service project.
Code below

```
public string SendMessage(string message)
    {
        SendMessageResponse receipt = new SendMessageResponse();
        try
        {
            receipt = this.requestClient.SendMessage(new SendMessageRequest()
            {
                QueueUrl = RequestQueueURL,
                MessageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>
            {
                { "Message", new MessageAttributeValue { DataType = "String", StringValue = "text"} }
            },
                MessageBody = message,
                DelaySeconds = 0
            });
        }
        catch (InvalidMessageContentsException invalidException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + invalidException);
        }
        catch (UnsupportedOperationException unsupportedException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + unsupportedException);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // need to change this console exceptions to log4net errors.
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            // ??
        }
        return receipt.MessageId != null ? receipt.MessageId : "failed";
    }
```

Comment: Breaking how?  Crashing to desktop? If  by breaking you mean "not sending the message" then what is the exact response from AWS?

Comment: neither sending the message nor going to next statement in code. simply stopping the program.

Comment: How long did you wait?  It might take a few minutes if there is some network problem.

Comment: no waiting at all, program is closing straight away after executing the function. But anyway there is no message in sqs even after hours. Do I need to do any other settings if I am using it in windows service?

Comment: one more interesting thing is that I can't receive the message either. I am declaring the AWSSQSClient in this way
    AmazonSQSClient requestClient = new AmazonSQSClient("secretkey", "secreteaccesskey", RegionEndPoint.APSoutheast1);

Comment: SQS should queue in seconds, I was thinking maybe a network connection problem connecting and sending to SQS.  Can you use a packet sniffer to see whether anything is being sent?

Comment: If you can set a breakpoint and single-step, look at receipt just after the call.

Comment: no result coming through the receipt. program is just quitting at that point.